# Why does one iPad have two MAC addresses?

Tags: networking, mac-address

This question (and others) is driving me nuts and I apologize because it is so basic. Do you know why there are two MAC addresses in iPad's interface table? Only the first digit is changed from a 4 to a 6. MAC address sites recognize one and not the other.

I am trying to figure out if I have been networked into a neighbor's security/surveillance system and thus mapping out what is linking to what. I am using IT tools app as well as searching many websites.

Any help with this question or the larger networking issue would be deeply appreciated. My system is very simple: DSL-router-iPad. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The MAC address is hard coded in the hardware.

If you have two MAC addresses it means that there are two network devices in your iPad.

I think it is the wireless and Bluetooth devices which return both a different MAC address.

I don't have any source however to prove this, since I'm not an owner of an iPad.

Comment: Ah! So a MAC address does not identify the object itself (1 pad) but rather a network device of which there can be several within the object. Thank you. Maybe a MAC search couldn't identify the second # because it was labeled "locally administered" meaning within the object and not the local network. Appreciate this.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, I confirm, as an owner of both an iPhone and an iPad - they both have 2 MACs, one for Bluetooth, another for WiFi. Furthermore, if you open the Settings app on your device, and go to General -> About, then scroll all the way down, you will see two entries: "Wi-Fi Address" and "Bluetooth" that can help you identify which MAC belongs to which interface.

*Sorry, cannot comment on answers yet, had to post a separate one.*

Comment: My concern was that the altered address does not identify either wifi or Bluetooth which differ by one digit at the end. I do have a cellular connection which only lists a phone number. Thank you for you input.